# Core Data with parentContext Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x169a2190> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: multithreading, core-data

I have following problem:

- In my app there is core data pattern that there is root NSManagedObjectContect with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType concurrency type, this context is responsible for parsing objects fetched from remote server.
- there is also NSManagedObjectContect set as root's childern with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType concurrency type.

The problem is that randomly when e.g. some data is parsing on root context and must be refreshed on main thread app crashes with information Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x169a2190> was mutated while being enumerated. 
I did research and I know that in general it means that objects from root context are mutated on thread x while being enumerated on thread y. I am sure for 99% that this is not my case because I know rules which have to be followed with multithreaded environment and with using core data. I wonder if it works in this way that:

1. Root context does some parsing.
2. During parsing app wants to refresh UI and it is done on main context.
3. During operation of refreshing main context fetches objects from parent context.
4. While fetched operation is executing, root context mutates fetched objects, because of parsing operation.

I do not know if this is right way?
Could you share with me your thoughts about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your setup is not ideal. Rather than having a *parent* context of the main context do the work and alter the objects, it should be a *child* context.

If you follow the following pattern, you cannot run into this problem:

```
Root context (background) saves to persistent store --> parent of
Main context (main thread) updates UI --> parent of
Worker context (background) handles web, parses, inserts, mutates etc.
```

When you *save* the worker context, the changes are pushed up up to the main context. If you, say, use a `NSFetchedResultsController` you can react to changes by implementing the delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I understand what you mean, but what I have is:          Root context (background) saves to persistent store --> parent of
Main context (main thread) updates UI --> parent of and my question is - if there is parsing operation on root context going on and during this operation app wants to update set A. Set A is fetched by main context (child of root context). During this fetch is lasting root context mutate Set A and becaouse of this mutating system throws exception like in title of the post - is it possible?

Comment: That's what I am saying. Don't parse on the root context, parse on the worker context. Only save to persistent store on the root context.

Comment: Ok, it seams reasonable - I will try to adapt your pattern to the app. Thanks for help.